# Firebase AppCheck custom provider

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check, harmonyos

Currently I'm trying to use a custom provider for `AppCheck` and according to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-provider), this implementation can be used to verify other platforms than currently allowed, more specific:

> - You want to verify devices using platforms other than Apple, Android, and the web. For example, you could create App Check providers for desktop OSes or Internet-of-Things devices.

Now since current [SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#set-up-project-and-service-account) that supports `AppCheck` is `Node.js`, my question is:

- How can I create a custom AppCheck provider for non allowed platforms to generate a token?

More specific, I'm trying to implement `AppCheck` for non Google Android phones, `HarmonyOS`.

But, `Node.js` SDK currently has one method to be used: [createToken(appId: string, options?: AppCheckTokenOptions)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.app-check.appcheck.md#appcheckcreatetoken) from where I should supply an `appId`, where this value is generated by Firebase when registering a new app:

[image]

In this case the app platform is compatible with `Firebase` (Android, iOS, web, etc). I can register as example a Google Android phone, but I can't register an **IoT** device, **HarmonyOS** phone, **Tizen** TV, etc.

How can I generate a new `appId` or how should be used `createToken(...)` method in those cases?
Also `REST API` [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/appcheck/rest) for AppCheck require `appId`.

**Edit:**

I've tested using same `appId` from a Google phone registered in console for a non Google phone and token can be used with enforced `Firebase` protected services, it works.

Also adding a debug token generated from a non Google phone to a registered Google phone in console it works, `Firebase` pass requests and response is received. But I think is not ok since a non Google phone impersonate a registered Google phone.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I understand.

`createToken()` does require a valid `appId`, but `appId` doesn't need to be for Android; it can be Web, Unity, or Flutter, as long as it's correctly registered in your Firebase project. In other words, you can create a dummy Web app in your project and use its `appId` to create a token.

Note that `createToken()` is for creating the token itself, not verifying you are creating the token for the legitimate device or not; that responsibility [falls on your shoulders](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-provider#create_the_token_acquisition_endpoint).

> Add to the endpoint logic that assesses the authenticity data. This is the core logic of your custom App Check provider, which you will need to write yourself.

> If you determine the client to be authentic, use the Admin SDK to mint an App Check token and return it and its expiration time to the client.